# problem with extern variable

Tags: c++, variables, extern

I have got 2 cpp files & a header file, which I have included in both cpp files.  It's like this:

abc.h

```
extern uint32_t key;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "abc.h"
uint32_t key;
int main
{
.............
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include "abc.h"

int main
{
printf("Key: %.8x\n", key);
.............
}
```

Now when I compile a.cpp, there is no error. but when i compile b.cpp it gives error
"undefined reference to `key'".  Please help me in finding the problem in this code.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are compiling `b.cpp`? Are you including the a.cpp as part of your build?

Answer (score 10):

To share a variable, you normally have something like this:

```
// A.h
extern int key;
void show();

//a.cpp
#include "a.h"

int main() { 
    key = 1;
    show();
};

// b.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

int key;

void show() { std::cout << "Key = " << key; }
```

There are a couple of points to not here. First of all, you put the `extern` declaration in a header, and include it in *all* the files that use the variable. Define the variable (without the `extern`) in one and only one file. Only one file should contain a function named `main`.

Edit: to build this, you compile each file by itself, but you have to *link* the two files together. For example, using gcc you could do something like:

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
gcc a.o b.o
```

The first compiles (but does not link) a.c. The second does the same with b.c The third actually links the two together and produces a binary image you can execute (traditionally named `a.out`, though, for example, on Windows this is normally changed to `a.exe`).

Comment: How is that different from the OP scenario? You defined key in b.cpp, he did it in a.cpp... what was wrong with his way of doing it?

Comment: This is building a single program from two source files; it looks the OP is trying to build two programs.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, I missed the fact that there are two mains. We need to teach the OP about compilation...

Comment: @Bruno: as it was originally posted, he showed the header being included only in one of the two source files.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly what the error message says. Abc.h *declares* the variable, but it doesn't *define* it. The line in a.cpp defines it. That is, a.cpp is where the physical storage of the variable appears. There is no such line in b.cpp, so when you try compiling that program, the linker is left without any storage defined for that variable.

If you had omitted the "extern" specifier in the header, then b.cpp would have compiled fine, but a.cpp would likely have given an error about multiple definitions.

The "extern" specifier plays a larger role when you have multiple source files in a single program. In that case, they would probably all include abc.h, but without "extern," each compiled object files would have its own independent definition of the same variable. The linker generally won't know what to do with that, and will probably complain, although I don't think it's required to do so. The fix is to use "extern" so each compiled file file only has a *declaration*. Then you pick *one* source file to place the definition in. You'd probably put it in abc.cpp since the declaration is in abc.h.

Answer (score 2):

**You are compiling two separate programs.** One cannot reference a variable from the other. The `extern` keyword is for referencing a symbol from one *object file* in another *object file* of the same executable being *linked*.

Answer (score 2):

The line from the header file is a *declaration*; it tells the compiler that the variable exists, but doesn't allocate any space for it. When you build a program from one or more source files, one of them must also contain a *definition*.

In your case, you have a definition in `a.cpp`, so that contains everything needed to build the program. `b.cpp` has no definition, so it will fail to link.

There are two solutions. Either copy the definition from `a.cpp` to `b.cpp`, or move it to a third source file and include that in the list of sources when building both programs.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are getting a link error? You need to include a.o when linking b, though if you really have "main" in both a and b that won't work.  You will need to make c.cpp which declares key, and link c.o into both a.exe and b.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` have `main()` functions defined, and you're only allowed to define one `main()` per program.  So, I assume what you're trying to do is share a header file between two programs.  In that case, add the line to `b.cpp` to define `key` and recompile:

```
uint32_t key;
```

This isn't the normal way to use header files.  Instead you write your functions to take `key` as a parameter.  Doing it this way sets up a global variable, which is generally frowned on.

`extern` is almost always used to set up a global variable (off the top of my head, I can't think of any other reason to use `extern`).  But if you want to use `extern` the way it's normally used -- without going into whether it should be used at all -- you would do the following:

- remove the `main()` function from one of the two files, for the purposes of this answer we'll remove it from `b.cpp`.
- Use the following two lines to compile and link your program (assuming gcc):

  `gcc -c -o b.o b.cpp`

  `gcc a.cpp b.o`

The `-c` option to `gcc` (first line) says "[compile only, do not link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c-76)."  It's the linking step that determines if all variables are defined, and they aren't defined when you compile `b.cpp`, but they are defined when you compile `a.cpp` (second line).